# What's the general equation of a 3D right cone? And the intersection of the 3d cone with a line?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I need to graph a cone about an arbitrary axis $Z'$ and a vertex with position vector $V$.

My cone has equation:

[Equation of the Cone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qcxU.png)

Now I need to find the intersections between this cone and a vector with a given system parametric equations. To do that I need to first simply this equation of the cone into a general form. According to Wolfram alpha, it is something like this:

$x^{2}-y^{2}+z^{2}+0.03xy+92x+15.3y-476z=-58710.88$

However, the graph of this function does not overlap perfectly with the original graph.

I found this paper that finds the intersection using matrices, but is way beyond my level. Can anyone tell me how this may be done?

https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/IntersectionLineCone.pdf

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: There’s often rounding and other errors when graphing the same surface defined in different ways. The coefficients in the W|A output might not be exact in the first place.

Comment: Your notation doesn’t make sense to me. In the numerator, you have $\times$ for some sort of vector product, while in the denominator it appears to represent a product of scalars. Also, the left-hand side of the equation is a scalar, but if $\times$ has its usual meaning of cross product when applied to vectors, the right-hand side is a vector. In any case, why can’t you simply expand the equation that you’ve got in terms of coordinates?

Comment: Maths exchanged auto-corrected my equation. It's fixed now.